# Nautilus is frozen, cannot be used, and cannot be killed

Tags: nautilus

I'm experiencing the weirdest problem right now. Nautilus is essentially not working right now. My desktop is frozen, clicking and right clicking doesn't work, I can't open anything in nautilus, etc. It simply is broken. The problem is that I can't exactly kill it with anything.

`while true; sudo killall -9 nautilus ; done` doesn't kill it.

I can't log out because I'm right in the middle of a long upload and I'm not going to kill it if I can help it. Is there something I can do to reload nautilus without logging out?

Comment: Possibly related: [uninterruptible wait](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183015/271830)

Answer (score 9):

FYI, I was having the same issue. In my case, it appears to be caused by a faulty mount point somewhere in my FS tree.

Specifically, the culprit was a samba mount (cifs) that failed due to me losing VPN. As nautilus mentions these under 'Network' in the left sidebar, I'm guessing this caused it to hang. As a work-around I remounted all my volumes (`sudo mount -a`) and now nautilus is responsive again.

Comment: this was my case; I had a couple of autofs directories in the left sidebar and they were not accessible. This caused nautilus to always timeout, no matter what. I'm not sure why deleting all nautilus configuration didn't solve this though, disabling autofs mounts did.

Comment: My case also, I just had one shared fs with `sshfs` and now I can't reopen or force to close nautilus, the best solution could be to uninstall (because it's not stable).

Answer (score 7):

When Nautilus stopped responding and couldn't be killed, it turned out I had `sshfs` hanged. So this helped to kill it:

```bsh
killall sshfs
```

When `sshfs` hangs, it sometimes causes a file browser to hang in such a way that it cannot itself be killed, but `sshfs` can still be killed. Killing `sshfs` in this situation makes it possible to kill (and restart) the file browser. Sometimes the file browser will quit when `sshfs` is killed; occasionally it might even start responding immediately and not have to be killed.

This does not always work, of course, because when a file browser such as Nautilus hangs, even in the specific scenario described here where `kill -9` was ineffective, it is not always due to a problem with `sshfs`. However, this does seem to be a fairly common cause of the problem.

Killing `sshfs` also stops other filesystem activity through `sshfs` mounts. When `sshfs` is malfunctioning, you probably want that. When it's not, and some other problem is hanging your file browser, you may not.

---

When a process can't be killed, even with `SIGKILL`, even by root--which is what the question here describes happening to `nautilus`--it's usually because the process is stuck in [uninterruptible sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223644/what-is-an-uninterruptible-process) (see also [3dGrabber](https://askubuntu.com/users/788897/3dgrabber)'s [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59348/nautilus-is-frozen-cannot-be-used-and-cannot-be-killed/1239387#comment1619437_59348)).<sup>1</sup>

It's normal for a process to enter uninterruptible sleep for very short periods of time. Processes communicate with the kernel through system calls. Some system calls, while executing, cannot be interrupted by [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)), so any signals sent to the process must wait until the system call has completed. Normally, that happens, and then the signal is received. *But when a system call that can't be interrupted hangs*, the process can never receive a signal, unless the hang can be stopped through some other means.

Killing a process is achieved [by sending it a signal](https://medium.com/@cloudchef/linux-process-states-and-signals-a967d18fab64). By default, the [`kill`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/kill.1.html) command sends [`SIGTERM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGTERM), which processes are free to handle however they want and is thus sometimes ineffective. The harsher way to kill a process is [`SIGKILL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGKILL) (which `kill -9` or `kill -KILL` sends). Processes cannot choose to ignore `SIGKILL`, *but they still do not receive it while in uninterruptible sleep*.

A common cause of prolonged uninterruptible sleep is malfunctioning drivers, including filesystem drivers. Drivers are often implemented as kernel modules, and while most kernel modules can be loaded and unloaded, once one is malfunctioning and unable to complete an operation, there is often no reasonable and safe way to force it to stop while continuing to use the system. To end a process that's stuck in uninterruptible sleep, it's usually necessary to reboot.

[FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) drivers are a major exception to this. When they malfunction, you *often* needn't reboot. With FUSE, the details of how a filesystem is accessed are implemented outside the kernel, in an ordinary program. To access data on a FUSE filesystem, a program will still make system calls, but the kernel delegates them through the FUSE module into a handler program.

`sshfs` is a FUSE filesystem driver. When data are accessed on an `sshfs` mount, a system call is performed that delegates work to an `sshfs` process. (Behind the scenes, to mount an `sshfs` filesystem, `/usr/bin/sshfs` was run. Or you may have run [the `sshfs` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/sshfs.1.html) manually.) If this malfunctions, it can cause the program attempting to access the `sshfs` filesystem to remain in uninterruptible sleep, *yet the `sshfs` process itself may remain killable*. When that process is killed, the system call becomes unstuck, returning an error code to indicate failure, and the program that made the system call can terminate or continue running.

Malfunctions causing prolonged uninterruptible sleep are not unique to `sshfs`. They can happen with any filesystem, FUSE or not, though if it's not a FUSE filesystem then you likely must reboot. And there are other commonly used FUSE filesystems where this *could* occur, such as `ntfs-3g`. It doesn't happen often with any filesystem, but in practice it *seems* to occur more often with `sshfs` than most other FUSE filesystems.

Any program making a system call that uses a malfunctioning filesystem driver could run into this. But you would usually at least be trying to access a file on an `sshfs` mount, and thus have some idea of what might be wrong. In contrast, file browsers frequently access data outside of where you are currently working, in order to avoid giving outdated information about things like what filesystems are currently mounted and how much space is available on them, and sometimes to fetch information in the background to build thumbnails.

---

<sup>1</sup> Another scenario where this could happen is when it's a [zombie process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). However, unlike a process stuck in uninterruptible sleep, a zombie processes rarely causes problems, since the only resource it takes up is a row in the kernel's process table. A zombie `nautilus` processes would typically go unnoticed. In particular, that shouldn't keep a subsequently executed `nautilus` process from managing the desktop.

Comment: If killall does not work, it could be that one has to hunt the sshfs process and kill it from the PID.

Answer (score 6):

Running the command

```
killall nautilus
```

fixed this for me - it may help a future visitor.

Comment: Yes. That was enough for me too. An FTP connection cause an issue and everything was frozen (mouse & keyboard included). From another computer, I was able to run that command and it came back to life.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

Remounting one of the external USB drives didn't work due to "device is busy".

`lsof` showed up that a file was held open by an already closed application.

`ps` showed that the application was still running, despite the already closed window.

`kill -9` didn't work on that application either.

As `umount -f` also just complained `device is busy`, I finally decided to disconnect the external drive's USB cable.

At that very moment, all pending `kill -9`s seemed to take place – both nautilus and the still running application closed and disappeared from my `ps` output.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `nautilus -q` already?

It exits (and restarts) nautilus. I use it when it hangs or when i need to "refresh" it after installing new nautilus context actions

Comment: Command hangs and nothing happens. Whatever's messed up here, it is _seriously_ messed up.

Comment: Still same here in Ubuntu 12.04. Nautilus hangs quite often and kill/killall does not show any effect. 'nautilus -q' just states "Could not register the application: Timeout was reached".

Comment: 12.10 and I get the same message "Could not register the application: Timeout was reached."

Comment: Same here, with Ubuntu 14.

Comment: This worked. Nautilus reacts again.